# Simple parallelization with shared non-threadsafe resource in Scala

Tags: multithreading, scala, parallel-processing

I frequently want to parallelize a task that relies on a non-threadsafe shared resource.  Consider the following non-threadsafe class.  I want to do a map over a `data: Vector[String]`.

```
class Processor { def apply: String => String }
```

Basically, I want to create `n` threads, each with an instance of `Processor` and a partition of the data.  Scala parallel collections have spoiled me into thinking the parallelization should be dirt simple.  However, they don't seem well suited for this problem.  Yes, I can use actors but Scala actors might become deprecated and Akka seems like overkill.

The first thing that comes to mind is to have a synchronized map `Thread -> Processor` and then use parallel collections, looking up my `Processor` in this thread-safe map.  Is there a better way?

Comment: I don't see why using Akka is overkill. For simple examples, it's even simpler than Scala actors (no distinction between receive/react, no need to manage the loop yourself, etc).

Comment: Akka is definitely not overkill, it's 1 single jar.

Comment: Ok, ok, I'll learn how to use Akka and stop making unsubstantiated claims...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of building your own synchronized map, you can use [`ThreadLocal`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ThreadLocal.html). That will guarantee a unique `Processor` per thread.

```
val processors = new ThreadLocal[Processor] {
  def initialValue() = new Processor
}

data.par.map(x => processors.get.apply(x))
```

Comment: You will also need to configure the ForkJoin pool to use a given number of threads explained at http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/parallel-collections/configuration.html

Comment: I think that's a 2.10 document.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively you try using an executor service configured to use specified number of threads explicitly:

```
  val processors = new ThreadLocal[Processor] {
    override def initialValue() = new Processor
  }

  val N = 4

  // create an executor with fixed number of threads
  val execSvc = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(N)

  // create the tasks
  data foreach {
    loopData =>
      execSvc.submit(new Runnable() {
        def run = processors.get().apply(loopData)
      })
  }

  // await termination
  execSvc.shutdown()
  while(!execSvc.awaitTermination(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS)) {
    ;
  }

  // processing complete!
```